# how to cofigure apache for work pgadmin with orher settings proxyserver

Tags: apache, server, pgadmin, pgadmin-4

i have configure my  /etc/apache2/sites-enabled 000-default.conf

```
    <VirtualHost *:80>
 

 ProxyPass /api http://0.0.0.0:3000
 ProxyPassReverse /api http://0.0.0.0:3000

 ProxyPass /socket.io ws://0.0.0.0:3000/socket.io
 ProxyPassReverse /socket.io ws://0.0.0.0:3000/socket.io

 ProxyPass / http://0.0.0.0:8080/
 ProxyPassReverse / http://0.0.0.0:8080/


</VirtualHost>
```

when I did this, pgadmin4 stopped working, I can no longer access myapi/pgadmin4,
but if I delete this config, pgadmin will work, what should I do to make it all work together?

I have the nuxt client server running on port 8080 and the backend server running on port 3000